# Is PHPDoc SomeObject[] notation meant to sequences only?

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, hashmap, phpdoc

phpDocumentor supports declaring an array that contains only items of a specific type, e.g. `SomeObject[]` or `string[]` as stated in http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html#arrays. However, I am not sure whether such notation is meant to indicate only a sequence (list) of the specified types or whether it is appropriate to use it for dictionaries (hashes) as well.

Such usage is no doubt right:

```
/** @var SomeObject[] $myList */
foreach($myList as $item) {
  // … Do something with the $item.
  // Every $item is an instance of SomeObject[]
}
```

But would this use be fine, too?

```
/** @var SomeObject[] $myDictionary **/
foreach($myDictionary as $ref => $item) {
   // … Do something not only with the $item, but with
   // the non-sequential $ref too.
   // Although every $item is an instance of SomeObject,
   // there is no clue, what the keys ($ref) are.
}
```

Or, say, without the `foreach`:

```
/**
 * @param SomeObject[] $dictionary
 * @param Ref $refObject
 * @return SomeObject
 */
function getByRef(array $dictionary, Ref $refObject) {
  // Just added a bit of complexity so that the example
  // is not totally dumb.
  $key = $refObject->getDictionaryKey();
  return $dictionary[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't document the keys, but you can specify the keys type.

```
@var array[string]string
```